# Not login whereas correct username and password in php

Tags: php, authentication

I have a class called `User` and a `php` file called `login.php`.I didn't success when i enter `username` and `password` to login whereas these are correct.I guess authenticate function in `User` class is problematic.I put my code.

```
login.php
<?php
  require_once("../../includes/functions.php");
  require_once("../../includes/session.php");
  require_once("../../includes/database.php");
  require_once("../../includes/user.php");
  $message = "";
  if ($session->is_logged_in()) {
      redirect_to("index.php");
  }
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
     $username = trim($_POST['username']);
     $password = trim($_POST['password']);     
  // Check database to see if username/password exist.
  $found_user = User::authenticate($username, $password);

  if ($found_user) {
      echo "in the found_user<br/>";
      $session->login($found_user);
      redirect_to("index.php");
  } else {
      // username/password combo was not found in the database
      $message = "Username/password combination incorrect.";
  }
  } else { // Form has not been submitted.
           $username = "";
           $password = "";
         }
  ?>
 <?php include('../layouts/admin_header.php'); ?>
     <h2>Staff Login</h2>
<?php echo output_message($message); ?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" value="<?php 
             echo htmlentities($username); ?>" />
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" value="
              <?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>" />
            </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
<?php include('../layouts/admin_footer.php'); ?>
```

and `user.php` file

```
class User{
public static function find_by_sql($sql=""){
    global $database;
    $result_set=$database->query($sql);
    $object_array=array();
    while ($row=$database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
        $object_array[]=self::instantiate($row);
    }
    return $object_array;
}
public static function authenticate($username = "", $password = "") {
      global $database;
      $username = $database->escape_value($username);
      $password = $database->escape_value($password);

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
      $sql .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
      $sql .= "AND password = '{$password}' ";
      $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
      $result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);
      $str="in aout<br/>";
      return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : $str;
  }
private static function instantiate($record){
    $object=new self;
    foreach ($record as $attribute=>$value) {
        if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
            $object->$attribute=$value;
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
private function has_attribute($attribute){
    $object_vars=get_object_vars($this);
    return array_key_exists($attribute,$object_vars);
 }
}
```